# Javascript identify whether the browser platform is desktop or mobile(may be/not from device width-height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

Question is as simple as above.

**How to identify whether the browser platform is desktop or mobile with javascript**

I was trying facebook ads network and it only works for mobile platforms and not for desktop platform.I was wondering how they get it because when I use toogle device toolbar in chrome it identifies the device as not desktop platform and ad is displayed.Can I know the exact code or something smooth and easy as they use to identify whether its desktop of mobile ?

Comment: Please can you provide what you have done so far? Also, I'm pretty sure this question has been answered already...

Comment: I just created an ad placement in facebook and placed it in my trial work it shows perfectly well when the platform is mobile(using chrome toggle) else it shows and consolelog error stating "Unsupported desktop platform".all other is just ordinary programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is stored in `navigator.userAgent` variable. For *desktop* Chrome is userAgent like:

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36"

for *iPhone* is like:

> "5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1"